Допускается ли вставная конструкция в СПП с изъяснительными и местоименно-определительными придаточными?
Такие СПП считаются нерасчлененными (присловными), и там придаточное относится к слову в главной части (к опорному глаголу или к местоимению). Получается,что они взаимно связаны.
В расчлененных СПП придаточное относится ко всей главной части (к предикативной основе). В этом случае главное предложение более самостоятельное. Это большинство обстоятельственных СПП.
Например:
(1) Я говорил тебе(?) точно это помню(?) ЧТО приеду. СПП с придаточным изъяснительным.
(2) Я рассказал ему ТО(?) в личной беседе, конечно(?) ЧТО известно мне.  СПП с придаточным местоименно-определительным.
Вопрос задан по теме.  Там участники сочли грамматику корректной.
Можно ли найти примеры в литературе с такими вставными конструкциями?

В справочниках подобные конструкции мне не встречались. Нужно детальнее изучить вопрос.

Спасибо, Серж, помогите по возможности разобраться.  Они даже на слух не кажутся правильными. Может, в разговорной речи встречаются, но разговорный стиль вообще особенный: неполные предложения, отступления от темы и т. д. Поэтому пользователи не всегда реагируют на некорректную грамматику, вот она и попадает в письменные тексты.

https://ask.fm/russian
